Unable to add a row field by field in ArcGIS Pro table using Python script
I have written a Python script that creates a table with at most one row. The user is prompted to input values for each field, and the table should be updated accordingly. However, while the code is properly receiving the input values, it fails to update the row in the table.
I have tried updating the row by each field individually as well as all at once, but neither approach works. Ideally, I would prefer to update the table field by field, rather than updating all fields in one go.
def create_metadata_table(table_path):
    #emptying table rows 
    rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table_path, ["OBJECTID"])
    if any(rows):
        arcpy.management.DeleteRows(table_path)
    else:
        print("table is empty. Updating Table..")

    #user input data 
    fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(table_path)] #list all field names
    default_values={"Units":"μg/m³","Avgp":"24-hour"}
    user_data=[];
    print(f"Fields in the table '{t_name}':")
    for field in fields:
        if field == "OBJECTID":  # Skip the primary key 
            continue
        value = input(f"Enter value for field '{field}': ")
        if value == "":               #if user skips input it takes default value
            if field in default_values.keys():
                value=default_values[field]
        user_data.append(value)
    
        # This part is not working correctly 
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table_path, [field]) as cursor:
             for row in cursor:
                row.setValue([field],value)
                cursor.updateRow(row)
    print(user_data)    
    print(f"Table updated")


This is more of a Python debugging question than a GIS one.  You build a user_data list then never use it, value is simply left over from the last input you prompted from the user

I created user_data just for debugging purpose.

You're mixing and matching old/archaic/deprecated cursors with DA cursors, but the real problem is the awful flow of control demonstrated here. Cursors work on a row-by-row basis -- Get used to working with rows, containing fields, because working with the software is a lot easier than trying to work against it.

I tried row by row as well, but it didn't work. No error was given but the row was not updated in table. FYI I'm not a developer.

No row was updated because there are no rows in the table (so you never reached the setField syntax error). Either you can Delete all rows, collect the contents in a loop, and Insert one row, or you can assume there is one row, collect the values, and Update the row.  Personally, I use a properties table mechanism, where the property and value are Inserted, each in one row together (but updated if it previously existed).

You do not need the following line.
row.setValue([field],value) #row is just a list so no setValue method

correct way would be by index,
row[0] = value

However as Vince Pointed out there is no row to update, so would need to do an insert cursor and would recommend the following, and un-nesting cursor out of the for loop one level.
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table_path, fields) as cursor:
     cursor.insertRow(user_data)

to make fields work in this sense would need to update list comprehension
fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(table_path) if field.name != "OBJECTID"]

finally can remove other object id check
if field == "OBJECTID":  # Skip the primary key 
        continue


Thanks, thats exactly what I did just now !
